# What is the mechanism by which lactones are hydrolyzed during a Wolff-Kishner reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I've been away from orgo for a few years but lately someone asked me a question about lactones during a Wolff-Kishner reduction.  I understand the basic mechanism of a Wolff-Kishner but I cannot figure out how a lactone gets hydrolyzed.  Can anyone help me with that step?

Here is a [link to the basic mechanism](http://www.cedricbrule.com/page.asp?rec=219&dossier=29) that mentions lactones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a general feature of the hydrazine reagent that is employed in Wolff-Kishner reductions. When attacking an ester’s (includes lactone’s) carbonyl function, the generated tetrahedric intermediate can break down to form a hydrazide as shown in the scheme below.

[image: hydrazide formation]

The carbonyl function is not reduced but the ester (or lactone) is hydrazinolysed.

One could assume that the displace alcoholate could reattack the carbonyl group to regenerate the ester/lactone. However, apart from hydrazine being much more nucleophilic than alcoholates, the resulting hydrazide is also stabilised much like an amide, and is therefore less reactive.